# Optimizing SpriteKit

Tags: ios, performance, optimization, sprite-kit

Here I was optimizing my sprite-kit code, trying to test my game-engine's boundaries.

Using the Instruments Time-Profiling I fixed most of my own issues, now the only bottleneck that stays is

```
37.0ms   66.0%  0,0       -[SKTextureAtlas textureNamed:]
```

(My game loads a lot of sprites from TextureAtlases every half second)
The weird thing is, it seems that consistently through most of my tests, it seems the pure NSString-comparisons of the name cause more then one third of the work in the above method.
Here the subtree:

```
15.0ms   26.7%  0,0         -[NSString caseInsensitiveCompare:]
15.0ms   26.7%  0,0          -[NSString compare:options:range:]
15.0ms   26.7%  0,0           -[NSString compare:options:range:locale:]
15.0ms   26.7%  6,0            CFStringCompareWithOptionsAndLocale
```

For something so performance-important, is the apple supplied string comparison really so bad here? Why can't they supply a simpler way of accessing Textures in the atlas, we don't need fancy strings here, it could be iterated by an int for all we care.

Any comparative experiences with this?

Comment: Have you preloaded the textures used in your game?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, avoid using `textureNamed:` (frequently) while the game is running. Even with preloaded textures it does take time that will accumulate.

Instead cache the needed textures locally (in the class using them) in individual ivars or NSArray or NSDictionary ivars.

Comment: *facepalm* I totally didn't think of that, thank you. In fact I already store all animations in a separate dictionary of array and this was fast too. Will report back on the performance difference.

Comment: I cached the textures via `std::unordered_map<std::string, __strong SKTexture*>` since my keys were std::strings anyway. 4 times faster then before, thanks!

Comment: This just saved me a ton of time! I could not figure out why my memory went through the roof and took so long to load. I though it reused textures if they have the same image name. Loading SKSpriteNodes spriteNodeWithImageNamed:  275MB 30secs to load. Tossing textures in a temp mutable dictionary and loading with spriteNodeWithTexture: 27MB less than a second to load.

Answer (score 1):

I made a Swift implementation of @LearnCocos2D's answer, which is to avoid loading the same textures repeatedly. I created an enum with static texture variables and a getter to access them:

```
enum GameTextures {
   case Hero
   case Foe

   private static let heroTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "hero-texture") ?? UIImage())
   private static let foeTexture = SKTexture(image: UIImage(named: "foe-texture") ?? UIImage())

   var texture: UIImage {
      get {
         switch self {
         case .Hero: return GameTextures.heroTexture
         case .Foe: return GameTextures.foeTexture
      }
   }
}
```

So when I need a texture, I can simply do this:

```
heroSpriteNode.texture = GameTextures.Hero.texture
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test to see if I get any performance improvements. Should you not be returning a texture instead of a UIImage? `var texture: SKTexture {...`

Comment: Good catch :) yes, I think I intended to init the images with the textures, but I wrote this too long ago to remember